Multiple http requests to backend with nodejs and sequelize
I am developing a service in NodeJS using Express and Sequelize as ORM. I am also using the Serverless Offline plugin to emulate AWS Lambdas and I also deploy my backend in AWS Lambdas. My question is if I can make some configuration either in code or in the database to allow concurrent requests to my backend. The service I am developing will be very busy with users and when making a few requests at the same time, my application fails because there are many connections to the database. What can I do to solve that?
I have tried to configure my sequelize connection pool as follows
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DATABASE,
    process.env.NAME_SECRET,
    process.env.PASS_SECRET,
    {
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: process.env.PORT_DB,
      dialect: process.env.DIALECT_DB,
      dialectOptions: {
        multipleStatements: true,
      },
      pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 1000,
        acquire: 15000,
        evict: 2000,
      },
    }
  );

Since they are AWS Lambdas, I have a connection pool for each lambda with a maximum of 5 connections per pool. Lastly, I tried to create a general pool for all the lambdas but I still have the problem that there are many connections. I'm worried that I won't be able to solve this, I'm just testing it with an endpoint that doesn't do much, I have other endpoints that make a lot of queries to the database and it would be worse to solve the problem there.

Where do the request fail because of running out of connections: in database level or in the lambda functions? Where is your mysql database hosted? On RDS?

I suppose the problem is at the database level, Sequelize responds with an exception saying that the database already has many connections. My database has a limit of 90 connections and if it is hosted on RDS
